# How do you get speech dictated without adding it to a grammar list?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition

I'm new to Speech Recognition, and I'm working on a project that will receive a command from a recognizable list.

For example, I would say "Play song". The computer would ask the song title, and I can say it. It will then compare my answer to my music library and find it.

I know how to add recognizable grammar to the SpeechRecognizer object, how to make the computer speak, and how to play a song in iTunes. I cannot, however, figure out how to get it to dictate or listen and interpret something that *isn't* in the grammar list. Is there a method I'm missing? Or not yet been simplified by Microsoft? I have no code to show for this, as I am not even sure how to search for this particular idea.

Of course, I could have the program read my entire library, but that's not an optimal solution considering I have tens of thousands of songs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Building a database of every song and every individual word used in the title, artist, album, and genre isn't actually that bad.  My multi-zone music player does that and it scans the library every night to keep the database up to date.

Comment: @Hightechrider Thanks for that. If you don't mind me asking, how does your multi-zone music player work? Is it proprietary? I was really hoping to do something like that eventually and wasn't sure how to attack it.

Comment: see demo on blog http://bit.ly/smarthomedemo  It's all .NET, drives multiple sound cards, ducks audio for announcements, and more ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speech recognition works by comparing the signal to grammars, so there really isn't a good way to get a result without a grammar.  Why not use the music library to generate the grammar list?  I'm sure the result will be much more satisfactory.  A really general grammar won't enable you to tell whether the user said "Madonna," "My Donna," or "Mad on a" with any sort of reliability.  You might want to narrow the grammars further by letting the user choose to say an artist, title or album before they say it.

Comment: At first I was skeptical, but you're definitely right. I tested out it's dictation of various artists, and it only got about 30% of the odd ones right. I tested it with the grammar and it was 100%. Much thanks.